# Automating a two-input mix with web audio

Tags: audio, web-audio-api

I want to implement a two-input mixer like the ones you find in effect plugins where you control the ammount of effect that you want. Controlling a value we can call 'mix' you can go from only the sound with the effect to only the original sound or anything in between.

It's quite easy with two gain nodes:

```
gainNode1.gain.value = mix;
gainNode2.gain.value = 1-mix;
```

And then we send both gain nodes to the output.

The problem is that I want to automate it with exponentialRampToValueAtTime(). If I call exponentialRampToValueAtTime on gainNode1 I want the other one to follow it with the formula (1-gain1).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sketch of one way to do this.  (Completely untested!)

```
// src is a constant source whose value is 1.
var gainExp = context.createGain();
var gainNeg = context.createGain();
gainNeg.gain.value = -1;

src.connect(gainExp);
gainExp.connect(gainNeg);
gainNode1.gain.value = 0;
gainExp.connect(gainNode1.gain);
gainNode2.gain.value = 0;
gainNeg.connect(gainNode2.gain);
gainExp.connect(gainNode2.gain);

gainExp.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(value, time);
```

What this does is create a gainExp node that has your exponential ramp.  This feeds into the gain of gainNode1 so that this ramp is applied to the input to gainNode1.

gainNode2 has its gain param inputs from gainExp and gainNeg so that gainNode2's gain is 1 - mix as desired.

Comment: That's a good idea, I never thought of using negative gains. I will test this as soon as I can to see if it works.

Comment: Oops.  The connections to gainNode2.gain are wrong.  gainExp should not be connected to gainNode2.gain.  I think it's enough to connect gainNeg to gainNode2.gain and set gainNode2.gain.value = 1.  The resulting gain should be 1 - ramp.  Let me know if it works!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!